# Hashmap value gets modfied while inserting values into the hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am reading a database and filling up a hashtable, my key is a string for example `"1-1"`, which is a string and it is unique (I checked many times) and my value is an object that has other objects as attributes. The problem is that when I am filling my hashtable, some of my entries end up with wrong values for one of the attributes namely  `MethodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold`.

The value is set correctly in the first iteration but when I reprint the same value in the next iteration or at the end of the loop, I end up with the wrong value

```
System.out.println("WE ARW IN THE LOOP "+methodtraceHashMap.get("1-1"));
```

For some reason, it feels like the last value that was set in

```
MethodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold = myresults.getString("ownergold");
```

gets assigned and put into the value in the hashmap corresponding to the entry with the key `"1-1"`. I am not really sure how to fix this.

```
ResultSet myresults = st.executeQuery("SELECT traces.* from traces");

    while (myresults.next()) {
        MethodTrace MethodTrace = new MethodTrace();
        Method method= new Method(); 
        Requirement requirement= new Requirement(); 

requirement=RequirementHashMap.get(myresults.getString("requirementid")); 
         method = 
MethodHashMap.get(myresults.getString("methodid")); 

        MethodTrace.setMethod(method);
        MethodTrace.setRequirement(requirement);

        //checking whether the method is present in the 
    //      superclasses


        MethodTrace.setGold(myresults.getString("goldfinal"));
        String reqMethod=MethodTrace.Requirement.ID+"- 
   "+MethodTrace.Method.ID; 
        String reqClass=MethodTrace.Requirement.ID+"- 
  "+MethodTrace.Method.Owner.ID;  


         MethodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold= 
 myresults.getString("ownergold"); 

         System.out.println(reqMethod+"-");

System.out.println(MethodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold);

        methodtraceHashMap.put(reqMethod, MethodTrace);
        System.out.println("WE ARW IN THE LOOP 
 "+methodtraceHashMap.get("1-1"));

    }
```

Comment: It appears that the `hashCode` method of your class is dependent on mutable properties. This never works, and should therefore be avoided.

Comment: Your key could be repeating resulting in overriding the previous objects. is this always unique - String reqMethod=MethodTrace.Requirement.ID+"- 
   "+MethodTrace.Method.ID; If not then try to make it unique by adding some other value to it.

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: Consider marking the class variables as final, and initialize them with a constructor.  Also, follow standard java naming conventions.

Comment: no it's not repeating I checked a 1000 times

Comment: If you are using java8 there are some useful methods available on Maps like putIfAbsent() instead of traditional put(), this prevents overwriting the key value pair
i.e methodtraceHashMap.putIfAbsent(reqMethod, MethodTrace);


traditionally you can use put method after checking following condition: if(!map.containsKey(key)){
}

Comment: i tried it it's not working

Comment: Man, then the value for that particular key is getting modified. 

Moreover declaration like `MethodTrace MethodTrace` are highly discouraged . It creates confusion , it should be **`MethodTrace methodTrace`** (small caps). Kindly refactor the code after renaming the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this and print the hashmap and see if you still have the overwriting issue

```
methodtraceHashMap.put(reqMethod+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis(), MethodTrace);
        System.out.println("WE ARW IN THE LOOP 
 "+methodtraceHashMap.get("1-1"));
```

Comment: the same problem still occurs

Comment: Print the hashmap and share results.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you debug your code with following temporary correction:

```
if (methodtraceHashMap.put(reqMethod, MethodTrace) != null)
   throw new RuntimeException("key '" + reqMethod + "' duplication");
```

As you use `String` as a hash map key, so you do not have problem with custom `hashCode`. I am sure, your key is unique and you have to find out what key exactly and then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you (or the library you are using) overridden the `hashCode` of the object you want to store in the `HashMap`. To fix this issue you should use a Map that isn's searching (and inserting) elements by it's hash code